# Get 5 different Dates on output

Tags: sql, postgresql

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.mt_get_user_graph_bal(
    p_interval character varying,
    p_from_date character varying,
    p_to_date character varying,
    p_user_id bigint,
    p_user_type smallint)
    RETURNS TABLE(date_time character varying, amount numeric) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
Declare
v_date_time varchar[];
v_amount numeric[];
BEGIN
    if(p_from_date = '')
    then 
    p_from_date = null;
    end if;

    if(p_to_date = '')
    then 
    p_to_date = null;
    end if;
        
        select 
        array_agg(x.updated_on),
        array_agg(x.closing_balance)
        from
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (updated_on::date) 
        to_char((cast(u.updated_on as date)::timestamp(6) with time zone at time zone 'Egypt'),'DD-MM-YYYY')::varchar as updated_on,
        ((u.closing_balance)::numeric(50,2)) as closing_balance
        from mt_payment_list u
        where u.status = 2::smallint
        and u.user_id = p_user_id
        and u.user_type=p_user_type
        and case when p_from_date is not null and p_to_date is not null then coalesce(u.created_on,u.updated_on)::date between p_from_date::Date and p_to_date::date else true end
        group by cast(updated_on as date),u.closing_balance,u.payment_id
        ORDER BY updated_on::date DESC,updated_on::date BETWEEN now() AND now() + '7 days'::interval, payment_id)x
        into
        v_date_time,
        v_amount;
        
        
        return query
        select 
        unnest(v_date_time),
        unnest(v_amount);
end;
$BODY$;
```

Output:

[image: This is my output]

I want output of only 5 days that is 19-07-2022, 21-07-2022, 26-07-2022, 29-07-2022 and 01-08-2022

Comment: If you need just these particular dates - why not adding them to the WHERE clause?

Comment: I wanted those dates in that form of intervals

Comment: I do not see intervals here - only dates and amount per day.

Comment: If you want to use non-contiguous dates then you cannot use `BETWEEN`, the interval I assume you are talking about. You will need to use something like `IN ('19-07-2022'::date, '21-07-2022'::date, '26-07-2022'::date, '29-07-2022,::date,  '01-08-2022'::date)`.